# Replace base64 images by uploaded urls of a nested object

Tags: javascript

I have data like this:

```
const currentData = {
  id: "u76u76h",
  type: "cardA",
  name: "Section 1",
  thumbnail: {
    src: "",
    alt: "",
  },
  data: {
    avatar: {
      dataType: "image",
      src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBXgFy56y56y56",
      alt: "avatar"
    },
    album: [
      {
        dataType: "image",
        src: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/album_image1.png",
        alt: "album_image1"
      },
      {
        dataType: "image",
        src: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/album_image2.png",
        alt: "album_image2"
      }
    ],
    cards: [
      {
        icon: {
          dataType: "image",
          src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBXgF",
          alt: "card_image1"
        },
        title: "新規事業企画担当",
        description: [
          "企画書だけでは、「新しいビジネスの良さを理解してもらう事」が難しい！",
          "アイディアを実際に使ってもらって実感してもらいたい！"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want to extract all the base64 urls (none https) and upload to cloud storage, and after uploaded the storage I want to update the uploaded urls to the data object above before saving the data object to the database. But the problem is the data structure is complicated and can be 2 or 3 or more in nested level. I am scratching my head to find a solution. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to view the whole object. Be careful if the object contains circular references.

And remove `isBase64Fake` function. Use isBase64 instead. I've added isBase64Fake only to check your object.

```js
function extractBase64(data) {
  const result = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof data[key] === 'string') {
      isBase64Fake(data[key]) && result.push({
        data,
        key,
        value: data[key]
      });
    } else if (typeof data[key] === 'object') {
      result.push(...extractBase64(data[key]));
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function uploadSomewhere(dataToUpload) {
  console.log('uploading...');
  setTimeout(() => {
    dataToUpload.forEach((item) => {
      item.data[item.key] = 'QWERTY';
    });
  }, 1000);
}

function isBase64Fake(str) {
  return /^data:/.test(str);
}

function isBase64(str) {
  if (!str) {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    window.atob(base64);
    result = true;
  } catch (e) {
    result = false;
  }
}


const currentData = {
  id: "u76u76h",
  type: "cardA",
  name: "Section 1",
  thumbnail: {
    src: "",
    alt: "",
  },
  data: {
    avatar: {
      dataType: "image",
      src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBXgFy56y56y56",
      alt: "avatar"
    },
    album: [{
        dataType: "image",
        src: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/album_image1.png",
        alt: "album_image1"
      },
      {
        dataType: "image",
        src: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/album_image2.png",
        alt: "album_image2"
      }
    ],
    cards: [{
      icon: {
        dataType: "image",
        src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBXgF",
        alt: "card_image1"
      },
      title: "新規事業企画担当",
      description: [
        "企画書だけでは、「新しいビジネスの良さを理解してもらう事」が難しい！",
        "アイディアを実際に使ってもらって実感してもらいたい！"
      ]
    }]
  }
};


const dataToUpload = extractBase64(currentData);
console.log(dataToUpload);
uploadSomewhere(dataToUpload);
setTimeout(() => console.log(currentData), 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I assign it back to the data object once the base64 urls area uploaded. We have to remember the location of the base64. Assume that when upload a base64 (image1), it will return a uploaded url like this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/image1.png

Comment: You can store a sub-object references and update them after upload. I've updated my answer to show how it works.

Comment: The image reference paths have to be something like this: data/avatar or data/cards/0/icon or even deeper when the data object's structure gets more nested. I did not see where you handle this when extract base64 urls or when assign uploaded urls back to the data object

Comment: The image reference paths do not matter and their nesting does not matter as well. Sub-objects are stored in the dataToUpload array I'm able to change their values in any moment.

Comment: I mean when you upload base64 image and get the uploaded url, and how can you update that url to the currentData, because the currentData is the one I also want to save to the database? the dataToUpload is just a collection of extracted base64Urls and it has nothing to do with the currentData

Comment: The dataToUpload contains references to the currentData sub-objects. Have you try to execute the code from my answer? The last console.log displays the currentData object with updated urls.

Comment: I have executed already and I did not see the currentData change, still there are base64...

Comment: Hm, it's odd. It looks like SO console works incorrect. I've updated my answer (added "QWERTY" to see if it displayed). Could you please execute my code in browser console?

Comment: Thank you, it works. Your solution looks simple and smart. Thank you very much

Comment: Ha ha, I understood why it is happening, I should wrap the last console.log in setTimeout because I'm updating sub-objects inside setTimeout